# Problem with gradle when importing io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

Every time i try to build or run from gradle (gradle bootRun or ./gradlew bootRun), while importing io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.Json,  i get this error:

Stack trace

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED
/home/repos/test-backend/src/main/java/com/dnt/backend/BackendApplication.java:3: error: package io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec does not exist
import io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.Json;
                                ^
1 error
```

##### Steps to reproduce

```java
package com.test.backend;

import io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.Json;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BackendApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendApplication.class, args);
        Json test = Json.of("testing");
        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.7'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.test'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '18'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

##### Expected behavior/code

When i debug-run the project from the IDE (vscode) it works and prints the Json object.

##### Versions

- Driver: 0.8.12
- Database: 14.2
- Java: 18
- OS: Linux 5.10
- Gradle: 7.4.2

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by changing the build.gradle to:

```
implementation 'io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql'
```

Answer (score 1):

It must be versioning problems, I tried this and it is solved:

```
implementation 'org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql'
```

Comment: yes, I was on Spring Boot 2.7.16, and your answer solved my problem. thanks